# Determine if the following vectors are coplanar.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, vectors

[image]

I have no idea to start with this question, I know how to find if vectors are coplanar when the values of the vectors are given to me, but I do not know how to manipulate coplanarity properties well enough to determine if the w vectors are coplanar or not.

Comment: the determinant of 2,7,0;0,1,2;-1,0,-7 is  -28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Take $\overline{v}_1$, $\overline{v}_2$, and $\overline{v}_3$ as a basis. This means:
$$\overline{v}_1=(1,0,0)^t$$
$$\overline{v}_2=(0,1,0)^t$$
$$\overline{v}_3=(0,0,1)^t$$
I know this might seem confusing at first, but since we are given that $\overline{v}_1$, $\overline{v}_2$, and $\overline{v}_3$ are not coplanar, they must be linearly independent (three non-coplanar vectors are always linearly independent), so this kind of change of basis is a valid mathematical step.

Comment: So I could just set the vectors as those, solve for the w vectors, and use the coplanarity method to determine if they are coplanar or not?

Comment: @AlexCharron Yes. However, before you use this "change of basis" method, you must verify that the vectors involved are linearly independent. Since we are given that these are three non-coplanar vectors, we can deduce that this is true, so in this case, the "change of basis" method is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\vec{w_1}+b\vec{w_2}+c\vec{w_3}=\vec{0},\;\;$ so $\;a(2\vec{v_1}+7\vec{v_2})+b(\vec{v_2}+2\vec{v_3})+c(-\vec{v_1}-7\vec{v_3})=\vec{0}$.

Then $(2a-c)\vec{v_1}+(7a+b)\vec{v_2}+(2b-7c)\vec{v_3}=\vec{0}$,

so $2a-c=0, \;7a+b=0, \;2b-7c=0$ since $\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \vec{v_3}$ are linearly independent.

Then $c=2a, \;b=-7a, \;2b=7c\implies -14a=14a\implies a=0, b=0, c=0$.

Therefore $\vec{w_1}, \vec{w_2}, \vec{w_3}$ are linearly independent, so they are not coplanar.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{w_1}\times \vec{w_2} \cdot \vec{w_3} = -28\vec{v_1}\times \vec{v_2} \cdot \vec{v_3}$.
Hence the box product $[w_1, w_2, w_3] \neq 0$ and the vectors are not co-planar.